# angular JS $http.get returns array, trying to put each array in $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I am using this $http.get call in my angular JS:

```
$scope.exportData = [];

$http.get('/reports?UserId=1').then(function (result) {
       $scope.exportData = result.data
});
```

`$scope.exportData` returns blank :(

but when I debug this I see that `result.data` is getting populated and `result.data` has 5 arrays in it...my question is how would I put each of those arrays in `$scope.exportData` `result.data` has a length value of 5. Maybe I could use that to do a foreach? I would know how to do that in php by javascript/jquery/angular js I am a newbie. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a screenshot on what gets populated for results.data:

[image]

Thanks,
J

Comment: Show us your HTML and how do you know $scope.exportData is blank?  Are you using batarang or ng-inspector?  I'm guessing that you're setting $scope.exportData to your 5 item array.  You're probably not implementing it right in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the nested function is not getting called. $http.get([url]) is a valid shortcut and thus may be populating result.data, however you do not specify the success or failure call backs.

Perhaps try:

```
$http.get('/reports?UserId=1').success(function (result) {
     $scope.exportData = result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

missing semi-colon after result.data

can also try

```
angular.forEach(result.data, function(item) {
  // set a break point here:
  $scope.exportData.push(item);
});
```

Comment: $scope.exportData still appears blank at the end and I did some debugging, nothing is coming up for item

Comment: each array is an oject